# Should I delete this very specific question, that has been answered on another site?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-delete

This is the question: [Is Infragistics Ignite UI 2014.2 (14.2.20142.1024) compatible with jquery 1.10.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064503/is-infragistics-ignite-ui-2014-2-14-2-20142-1024-compatible-with-jquery-1-10-2)

I asked it hoping that someone else might have stumbled upon the same situation. 
The chance was small, so we also asked on another forum and got an answer [there](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/93410/462039.aspx#462039).

Google searches seem to find both questions, so I don't think that by deleting it from stack overflow we deprive users of information. Should I delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to self-answer here, using the information (but not the wording) from the answer at infragistics.com, and including a link to the answer there, as an acknowledgement of your source*.

If you feel bad about earning rep from simply rewording information you got elsewhere, simply mark your answer as community wiki. This, along with your clear references in your answer to the answer at infragistics.com, will allow you to not take credit for the work.

<sub>* In this case, there's another reason to include the link: it's an *official* source, as the answer came from someone associated with the product.</sub>